# install4j and pref-jre.cfg

Tags: java, install4j

We have a few customers who are getting a JVM Error when running our application which is built with install4j.  In most cases they have a pref-jre.cfg file in the .install4j folder which is incorrect. Such as they upgraded their java version, and the java reference in pref-jre.cfg no longer exists. So editing that file to point to the right location fixes the problem.

However, I cannot figure out how the pref-jre.cfg got there in the first place.  The application install does not create it, we didn't advise them about that, and they are not sophisticated enough to create one.

Does anyone have any idea about what situations might automatically create that file?

Or, in general, how is install4j supposed to be handling updates of the Java environment?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The installer writes the path of the JRE that it is running with to `pref_jre.cfg`. If that JRE is a bundled JRE, the corresponding location in the installation directory is written instead. You can set the value yourself with the [API](https://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/api/com/install4j/api/JVMSelector.html), Any installed launcher will use that JRE. If the version changes and becomes incompatible or if the path no longer exists, the launcher will perform the JRE search sequence configured on the "General settings->Java version" step. If no JRE can be found with that search sequence, an error will be displayed.

Comment: That makes sense, although on 3 out of the 4 systems I tested with, no pref_jre.cfg is created.  Just inst_jre.cfg.

But as I dig into the main issue, which is that launch errors are occurring, it looks like when running the local jre, PATH  is including all kinds of other java installs on the customer's computer. And I think that is the cause of the problem when it occurs.  How can PATH be defined or controlled?  

The only possible option I could see is the  the option in Java Version for where install4j searches for the jre?  Is that it, or is there something else I am missing?
Thanks

Comment: `inst_jre.cfg`contains the actual JRE that the installer was running with, `pref_jre.cfg`  is written if the preferred JRE is different. The PATH is never searched. You can debug the search sequence by passing the argument `/create-i4j-log` to the failing launcher.